# Lazy-load Custom Material DatePickerModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, lazy-loading, angular-module

I have written a DatePickerModule that configures my Material Datepickers:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [],
declarations: [],
exports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule]
})
export class DatePickerModule {

static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: DatePickerModule,
        providers: [
            { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de' }, // inject locale value...
            { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
            { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT }
        ]
    };
}

static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: DatePickerModule
    };
}

}
```

In my core module I call DatePickerModule.forRoot(). In all lazy-loaded modules I call DatePickerModule.forChild(). Unfortunately, the Datepickers  do not work as expected in my lazy-loaded modules. It seems that my lazy-loaded modules can not access the providers or do not know them, as the Datepickers appear in default configuration. Why does this not work?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: no, unfortunately not yet.

Comment: I found you must only import the MAT_DATE_FORMATS and the CustomDateAdapter in you main app module.  That way any lazy loaded modules will inherit the providers from the root

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your input. Meanwhile the formatting works fine. There was an issue with multiple registrations of same material components in different modules. The other issue I still have is the language switch across all modules. I'm going to open another question.

Comment: got the same issue :(